# Rake task identifying the environment as development ruby and sinatra

Tags: ruby, rake-task, whenever, sinatra-activerecord

I have written a scheduler using "whenever gem". one of my scheduler runs a rake task everyday. This rake task calls a method in my model and performs activerecord operations.

everything works fine, but the activerecord connects to "development" environment in the database.yml file and connects to development database while in production.

```
config/schedule.rb 

set :output, "log/cron_log.log"

every 6.hours do
  rake "sidekiq:restart"
end

every :day, :at => '01:00am' do
  rake 'prune_users:older_than_2months'
end
```

Rakefile

```
require 'newrelic_rpm'
require './app.rb'
import './lib/tasks/sidekiq.rake'
import './lib/tasks/reap_user.rake'
import './models/exportuser.rb'
```

/lib/tasks/reap_user.rake

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'

namespace :prune_users do

  desc 'Delete 2 months older users with status non-active'
  task :older_than_2months do
    ExportUser.delete_users_b4_2months
  end

end
```

/models/exportuser.rb

```
class ExportUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'exportusers'

  def self.delete_users_b4_2months
    begin
      @old_users = ExportUser.where("status != ? and Modified < ?", "Active", 2.months.ago)
      puts "Count of users before 2 months with non-active status on #{Time.now}"
      puts @old_users.count
      @old_users.find_each do |users|
        users.destroy!
      end
    rescue => err
      NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(err)
    end
  end

end
```

Everything works fine, but in ExportUser.rb, the activerecord connects to development database. How to make it connect to production.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application should honour the `RACK_ENV` environment variable.

Try issuing the following command:

```
user@server $ RACK_ENV=production rake prune_users:older_than_2months
```

and verify whether it connects to the production database.  If it does, you need to change whatever invokes your scheduled jobs to also include the `RACK_ENV` environment variable

Comment: Thanks for your solution!!! yes it worked :). but where should I specify this "RACK_ENV" in the code??

Comment: @joe you could always hard-code it in the code with `ENV['RACK_ENV']='production'` but that's bad practice.  I'm unfamiliar with how Sidekiq is configured, but there will be an option somewhere that will allow you to either do this via a config yaml file or else via an environment variable.

Comment: Yes I have added ENV['RACK_ENV']='production' in my "reap_users.rake" file in first line. It worked fine.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `ENV['RACK_ENV']='production'` in first line of rake task file "`reap_users.rake`" file before `require 'sinatra/activerecord'`. it worked fine :)